# How to use inheritance with Swift and ObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I'm new to Swift and I have to serialize an object structure into a JSON string in my iOS( iOS >= 8) project.
So I decided to use the ObjectMapper library (I integrated it with Cocoapod).

But my problem is that the structure is the following.

ObjectA can have a list of children objects as an array stored in an instance variable. 
Objects that can be stored in the instance array can be of multiple types, say ObjectB and ObjectC. So, in Java with GSON I would have created an InterfaceD and made both of my classes implement it and made the array in ObjectA store InterfaceD types, but I can't figure how to do this with Swift object model as it results in empty `{}` JSON objects.

The resulting JSON should look like this.

```
{"children":[
  {"type":"ObjectB", "value1":"foo"},
  {"type":"ObjectC", "value1":"bar", "value2":"baz"}
]}
```

and I get

```
{"children":[
  {},
  {}
]}
```

Notice that the two entries that have to be serialized from objectA and ObjectC should have different structures.

I tried multiple things but each times I'm stuck in a dead end.
I tried using generics, tried to use Mappable protocol as my array type, I tried classic class inheritence but any one failed.

Have you any idea how I can achieve this ?

Note that I know that I could add a serialization function to each object and retrieve the strings recursively and concatenate them. But I really want to avoid implementing a JSON serializer by myself as I already use on successfully as Alamofire is already used in the project). Also implementing a new serializer is error prone and not a clean way to solve the problem IMO.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never had the solution but as a workaround I just made my objects produce a dictionnary from all its values. Then I recursively add child objects dictionnaries as the current dictionnary values.
It adds a toDict() function to each object that I forced with a protocol.
When the resulting object is only made of a tree of dictionnaries, the ObjectMapper serialization works fine...